# Clean URL - redirect 301 from URL with question mark to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

Original url: **example.com?file=gallery&d=doc**
I want: **example.com/gallery.html**

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?file=$1&d=doc [L]
```

(removed d=doc from url because this not needed)

Now clean URL's work but I want 301 redirect all old URL's (**?file=example&d=doc**). Anyone can help me with .htaccces? Now page is availiable from  **example.com?file=gallery&d=doc** and **example.com/gallery.html** but should be **ONLY** from **example.com/gallery.html**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.med-pro.pl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://med-pro.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?plik=$1&d=doc&r=0 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^plik=([^&]*)&d=doc$
RewriteRule .* %1.html? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I added this to my .htaccess and now my url look like this: http://example.com/location.html?file=location&d=doc - this htaccess add after .html ?file.. But I want redirect all old url's to new subpages - only location.html

Comment: that means there is an infinite loop happening, what else do you have in your htaccess

Comment: `RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.med-pro.pl$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://med-pro.pl/$1 [R=301,L]  
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?plik=$1&d=doc [L]  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^plik=([^&]*)&d=doc$  
RewriteRule .* %1.html? [L,NC,R=301]  `

@Yazmat This is my full htaccess with your mod and live site address (polish lang).

Comment: This is my full htaccess with your mod and live site address (polish lang)

Comment: The last tow redirect rules are looping with each other, you want to redirect anyone that uses params to .html and anyone that use .html to params ... let me thin kabout a solution

Comment: I updated the code (I added a third parameter for the .html line so that it does not get redirected again if this param is present